# What does the parallel operator do in SQL SET?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The table meat_poultry_egg_inspect is being updated where column zip is being set to something wherever column st matches with PR, VR and length of zip is 3. I think its making the zip column into a five digit value:  '00 + zip'.

```
UPDATE meat_poultry_egg_inspect
SET zip = '00' || zip
WHERE st IN('PR','VI') AND length(zip) = 3;
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` is the operator for [string concatenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL).

This is the SQL standard operator, although not all databases support it.